# Similar elements from lists

Tags: list, numbers

With given N lists of M numbers in each list we have to find ONE element from each group such
every pair ai aj gives |ai-aj| as small as possible.

For example
we have 3 lists

```
{12,16,67,43}

{7,17,68,48}

{14,15,77,54}
```

And to minimize result we have to pick 
number 16 from list 1
number 17 from list 2
number 15 from list 3
so

```
|16-17|=1
|16-15|=1
|17-15|=2
```

so our result is :2

How to solve it fastly? in N*M time ? or log something time

Chris

Answer (score 0):

If you use a linear search, the complexity is O(N*M) for one match (i.e., for each element in set j, do a linear search for the most similar item from set i, and pick the smallest of those results.

If you sort each set first, you get to (at least) O(N log N)+O(M log M) for the sort, and O(M log N) for the searches (where N is the number of elements in set i, and M the number of elements in set j). If you walk through the two sets together you can probably reduce that to O(N + M) for the combined search.